# Can't run Visual Studio 2022 debugger on React app (.esproj) without `.vscode/launch.json` file? Why?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, debugging, visual-studio-2022

I've been searching high and low for an explanation on this, or a workaround, and there's nothing out there. I've googled, I've tried ChatGPT-4 for an explanation, and nothing. Can anyone explain to me why a javascript project in Visual Studio 2022 (not VS code to be clear!), a `.esproj` file, needs the folder `.vscode` with a `launch.json` file in it to launch the debugger properly in VS2022.

I have been told that including your `.vs` and/or `.vscode` folder isn't needed when commiting my code to github or some kind of code base, but when I left out the `.vscode/launch.json` and then clone my repository, the project doesn't run as expected when I do a multiple launch (because it's a full stack app with an ASP.NET backend). If the `.vscode/launch.json` is missing, it just breaks the whole thing.

I can't find any kind of explanation in any documentation, so any links would be appreciated, or any kinds of suggestions for best practices.

EDIT:

Ok so there is a single note [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022):

> Note
>
> launch.json stores the startup settings associated with the Start
> button in the Debug toolbar. Currently, launch.json must be located
> under the .vscode folder.

But it doesn't really explain why VS 2022 needs VScode folder structure/files. Anyone know this?

Thank you.

Comment: weird... are you sure this is Visual Studio and not VS Code that you're using?

Comment: @starball yes. It's VS 2022, not visual studio code.

Comment: it might just be a consistency thing, so that you can reuse the file when using VS Code without having to move it around or create copies / symlinks of it? (just a guess)

Comment: @glitchwizard Hi, have you checked my answer, does it answer your question? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can get from the ["Set the project properties part"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022#set-the-project-properties)

This configuration is needed in Visual Studio.

But this does not mean that the project created by Visual Studio itself has any dependencies on VSCode, it is just where the configuration file is located, nothing more.

The original intention of this design is just to allow projects that was able to be debugged in VSCode to be debugged directly in Visual Studio without cumbersome configuration migration.

In VSCode, it is just a configuration file path too:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/reactjs-tutorial#_configure-the-debugger

**We can't think that it is unique to VSCode as soon as we see that the folder is called .vscode, or that the created project must be based on VSCode because the folder is .vscode. This is just a configuration file path.**

Comment: How do you set up debugging for an .esproj without using the .vscode folder then? I'm missing that part

Comment: because frankly, that's not very intuitive and pretty confusing to see a dependency on a folder that most developers would assume is specifically for VScode, because it's literally named as such, and when removing a folder that would appear at a glance to be unnecessary to clean up a repo breaks your debug setup out of the gate. I dunno, looks pretty smelly to me.

Comment: I guess it does answer the question though, even if I don't like the answer.